# What is the proper/recommended way of getting an std::vector iterator now that std::vector::iterator is legacy?

Tags: c++, std

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
iterator    LegacyRandomAccessIterator
const_iterator  Constant LegacyRandomAccessIterator
```

Is it not supposed to be used anymore?
What's the proper/recommended way of getting a `std::vector iterator`? Are we supposed to be using the only `auto`?

Comment: *Legacy* does not mean what you think it means. Where did you get the assumption that it implies something among the lines of deprecation?

Comment: @Fureeish "Deprecated means that it will be removed in the near future, and Legacy means that it will remain for backwards compatibility or other reasons. Both mean that they shouldn't be used by new code." First result in Google search of an SO answer. That question was related to Java.

Comment: There are a lot of _implementation defined_ already mentioned in the standards. That doesn't mean you can't use these safely in your c++ code.

Comment: There lies your confusion - you read an answer for Java, not for C++. It was also about API, not about the very name of a concept (not necessarily `<concepts>` related). [LegacyIterator is a name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Iterator). I don't know why it's named like that, but it's just a name.

Comment: It is the "category" which is marked as legacy (as C++20 `concept` use same naming).

Comment: By the way, apart from a confusion assumption made by OP, I think this is a good question. There are surely reasons for naming (already mentioned in an answer) and I think  it's likely that people can get confused by such naming, especially since there is no easy to access explanation.

Comment: @Zebrafish — despite that quotation, deprecated does not mean “it will be removed in the near future”. It means that it **could be** removed **sometime** in the future. For example, the C library headers were deprecated in C++ 98 and all the standards since then. They have not been removed.

Answer (score 5):

Saying `legacy` doesn't mean that it's not supported or deprecated. It just means that it's not new, hence using the term `legacy`. `Legacy` prefix is used only to differentiate between C++20's `RandomAccessIterator` and the pre-existing `LegacyRandomAccessIterator` (both are "concepts" according to C++). I don't think the term `Legacy` is actually mentioned in the standard, though.

Comment: The term "Legacy" does not appear in the standard. It is an invention of cppreference.com. I think a less confusing term would have been "Classic". There's nothing wrong with the classics. But they are also not modern.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I did some digging and I believe the site operators did so to separate the wiki pages, I maybe wrong.